# How to write to a zip file using actionscript 3

Tags: flash

I'm using the Adobe Creative Suite Extension to create a plugin to Flash CS 5.5 and I need create a zip file with 3 entries. I need to use an external library or I can use pure flash?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ByteArray.compress](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#compress%28%29) method. It supports several compression algorithms. As far as I know ZIP can use [many compression algorithms as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29). After compressing your ByteArray you will probably need to add a proper header and write all the data to a file.

Also you can use [FZIP](https://github.com/claus/fzip) AS3 library.

Comment: Good, But I need to generate a zip with 3 files. FZIP do this?

Comment: Yes, check out the [API](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-zip/asdoc/index.html).